# Foundation "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import"

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm, zurb-foundation

I'm taking over development from a previous developer who added Zurb Foundation as a framework to our website. Foundation has been installed with npm. I'm getting errors in the console for all of the foundation javascript files as follows:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Checking the code, `foundation.core.js` has the lines:

```
"use strict";

import $ from 'jquery';
import { GetYoDigits } from './foundation.util.core';
import { MediaQuery } from './foundation.util.mediaQuery';
```

I'm including jQuery right before any other JS is included in my HTML doc. Not sure what the deal is here. Can anyone offer help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for an as would be the following:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { GetYoDigits } from './foundation.util.core';
import { MediaQuery } from './foundation.util.mediaQuery';
```

This is saying to take all exports from the node module jquery and make them live under the keyword $. You should then be able to use $ as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way you import it

"use strict";

```
import {$} from 'jquery';
```